# SAML2. Issue with signature validation

Tags: ruby, wso2, saml, saml-2.0

I try to add SSO (single sign-on) and use SAML2 protocol. We use WSO2 as an identity provider and implement service provider as a Sinatra web app. We use `ruby-saml` gem on the Sinatra's side.

It works well until we add certificates and switch on signature validation. Service provider checks responses successfully, but WSO2 identity provider rejects requests because signature validation error.

We've rechecked certificates, domains... All is correct. According to debug logs of WSO2 we fail in `org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature`... We aren't able to see debug logging from this class so cannot precisely find out the reason of failure.

Logs of WSO2 identity server:

```
DEBUG -  Attempting to validate signature using key from supplied credential {org.opensaml.xml.signature.SignatureValidator}
DEBUG -  Creating XMLSignature object {org.opensaml.xml.signature.SignatureValidator}
DEBUG -  Validating signature with signature algorithm URI: http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256 {org.opensaml.xml.signature.SignatureValidator}
DEBUG -  Validation credential key algorithm 'RSA', key instance class 'sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl' {org.opensaml.xml.signature.SignatureValidator}
 WARN -  Signature Validation Failed for the SAML Assertion : Signature is invalid. {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.util.SAMLSSOUtil}
DEBUG -  org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityException: Signature Validation Failed for the SAML Assertion : Signature is invalid. {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.util.SAMLSSOUtil}
 WARN -  Signature validation for Authentication Request failed. {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.SPInitSSOAuthnRequestProcessor}
```

---

Could you suggest any reason of failure other then "you use wrong certificate"

Comment: just to make sure how did you add the public certificate of the SP app to the keystore of IS?

Comment: @farasath We have tried both ways. We have imported certificate via WSO Management Console (Home  > Configure  > KeyStores  > View KeyStore) and have added it into key store manually with `keytool` CLI command.

Comment: Does your cert support RSA SHA256?